# Ternary operation in swift what is this "?" symbol

Tags: ios, swift

I recently been following a guide and noticed that they wrote a line that I haven't seen before and I have no clue what it's called, and how's it working.

`let title: String = isPaused ? "Start" : "Pause"`

So the property `isPaused` has the type of Bool, but what does the questionmark stand for? And is this some kind of a "switch" statement, when the value could either be `Start` or `Pause`?

And the last question, what is this kind of operation even called?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Is called **ternary operator**, and is not a feature only of ***Swift*** programming language, **ternary operator** is supported for almost all of major programming languages as you can read here [Ternary Operator Wikipedia Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:)

basically you are doing an **if else** statement in one line

this `let title: String = isPaused ? "Start" : "Pause"` is **equivalent** to this

```
 let title: String
 if isPaused {
     title = "Start"
 } else {
     title = "Pause"
 }
```

Comment: Really good to know! Thanks a lot! :) It was hard to google it, because I didn't even know what to search on.

Comment: Sounds good! I'll edit it right away!

Comment: awesome @JacobAhlberg best regards and happy coding

Answer (score 1):

Basically it is If and else condition. (Ternary operator)
So, if **isPaused** is **true** then **title** will be equal to `String Start` otherwise it will be equal to `String Pause`

Answer (score 1):

It's the Ternary Conditional Operator, it's a sort of inline if.

You can see the full description here under Ternary Conditional Operator:
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Answer (score 1):

It's a shortHand for

```
var title = "Pause"
if isPaused  {
   title = "Start"
}
```

Comment: checking with Dissasembly seems to indicate that the if + else is closer to what ternary does. (No optimization -Onone)

Answer (score 0):

This is one kind of operator used in programming. We call it as conditional operator. The conditional operator is a special operator with three parts, which takes the form **question** ? **answer1** : **answer2**. It’s a shortcut for evaluating one of two expressions based on whether question is true or false. If **question** is true, it evaluates **answer1** and returns its value; otherwise, it evaluates **answer2** and returns its value.

The ternary conditional operator is shorthand for the code below:

```
if question {
   answer1
} else {
   answer2
}
```